# Access methods or properties from html in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

Ok this seems like an easy one:

In c# asp.net mvc I can declare some public class like:

```
public class Foo {
   public static string Bar {get
   {return "bar";}
   }
}
```

and access it from any html like:

```
<%=Foo.Bar;%>
```

right?

Well, I have to do the same in ASP.NET MVC VB.Net but I cannot access any variable or method:

```
public class Foo
   public Shared ReadOnly Bar as string
   Get
      return "Bar"
   end Get
   End Property
End Class
```

trying to do <%=Foo.Bar;%> does not work in vb.net I get Name 'Foo' is not declared.

What am I missing here?

---

**UPDATE:**
Ok standard VB.NET puts modules in the namespace defined in your project.

I had to type

```
MVCApplication1.Foo.Bar
```

Any suggestions on how to create a module that doesn't wrap this into a namespace? Or have the view import the application namespace by default?

---

**UPDATE:**
Oh I can answer that question myself too: in the web.config:

Comment: Seems to me that the problem is not VB vs C#. Check that 1) your web.config is referencing your VB.NET assembly; and 2) you are using the proper namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Recompile you project

oh and your property is missing the property keyword

try this :

```
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Bar As String
    Get
        Return "Bar"
    End Get
    End Property
```

Comment: Ofcourse I've compiled my project, the code you see is pseudo code. I'm wouldn't create a foo bar class in the real world.

Comment: Do you have a refrence to the assembly in your web.config ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the imported namespace to the web.config:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <pages>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="MyCompany.Application" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web></configuration>
```